# DriveApp in google apps script is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple script to create a pdf of a google sheet and save it in a drive folder however when I run the script I get this error: 
TypeError: Cannot find function getFolderByID in object Drive.

I noticed that DriveApp is black and not blue. I am wondering if this is the problem and how to fix it.

```
function MakePDF() { 
  var Testsheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test PDF'); 
  var FolderID = Testsheet1.getRange('B40').getValue(); 
  var pdfName = "TestConvert" var folder = DriveApp.getFolderByID(FolderID); 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder)); 
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName); 
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you write `Drive.getFolderById()` instead of `DriveApp.getFolderById()` ?

- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

You were very close to making it work.  I'll post your version in your question and here's my corrected version.  You can do a file compare to see the differences.

```
function MakePDF() { 
  var Testsheet1=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test PDF'); 
  var FolderID=Testsheet1.getRange('B40').getValue(); 
  var pdfName="TestConvert"; 
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID); 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var destSpreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder).getId());
  var theBlob=destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName); 
  var newFile=folder.createFile(theBlob); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true); 
}
```

By the way, if you would have posted your code in your question it would have  probably never put on hold and would have been answered very quickly.

Comment: function MakePDF() {
  var Testsheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test PDF');
  var FolderID = Testsheet1.getRange('B40').getValue();
  var pdfName = "TestConvert"
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderByID(FolderID);
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder));

  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}